# How do I create a new Project in IDEA using IDEAScript?

Tags: ideascript

I am trying to change the Project Directory, but I am receiving the error `Invalid working directory`  My Code is below.

```
Sub Main
  Client.Project = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to create the directory where you want to put the project using the code

```
MkDir("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\")
```

Next, you need to choose a type of project.

**Managed Project**

According to IDEA documentation

> IDEA lets you organize your workspace by storing local Desktop projects in one directory. With Managed projects, IDEA lets you define the location, selection and usage of audit projects as well as provide you with a better format for externally managing files for backup.When you create a Managed project, IDEA uses the Managed project name to create a self-named sub-folder in the C:\Users\YOUR USERID\Documents\My IDEA Documents\IDEA Projects directory (or the user-defined directory if you changed this default setting in the IDEA Options dialog box) where you can store all associated project files. Associated project files can be further organized into the Library sub-folders that are created within the project folder. When working with IDEA ServerIDEA Server is a powerful data analysis application that operates using network servers. While you view the data and perform your analysis using the IDEA client installed on your computer, all your data storage and processing is done on a server. For more information, visit the IDEA Server area on the CaseWare Analytics web site., you can link your Managed project to an IDEA Server project.

```
Client.ManagedProject = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\"
```

**External Project**

According to IDEA documentation

> All local Desktop project folders located outside the defined Managed projects directory are known as External projects. External projects can be pre-IDEA Version Nine Working Folders or new Desktop projects that you create and store outside the defined Managed projects directory. When IDEA creates an External project folder it also creates Library sub-folders within the project folder to further organize the associated project files. When working with IDEA ServerIDEA Server is a powerful data analysis application that operates using network servers. While you view the data and perform your analysis using the IDEA client installed on your computer, all your data storage and processing is done on a server. For more information, visit the IDEA Server area on the CaseWare Analytics web site., you can link your External project to an IDEA Server project.

```
Client.ExternalProject = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\"
```

So your full code if you are using a Managed Project would be

```
Sub Main
  MkDir("C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\")
Client.ExternalProject = "C:\Users\user1\Desktop\test\"
```

End Sub